# A problem with similar taste to Collatz Conjecture: Stochastic methods?

Tags: stochastic-processes, dynamical-systems, brownian-motion, collatz-conjecture

I am studying a problem which I think has a striking resemblance to the Collatz conjecture.
Essentially, given a natural number $k_0$,  there is an algorithm which produces another natural number $k_1$ and this process repeats, giving us a trajectory for $k_n$, essentially a dynamical system.

### The Algorithm

Fix real numbers  $\omega_1, \omega_2 > 0$.
Given $k > 0$  integer, find an integer $n$ such that

\begin{equation}
k = n+ \lfloor \tfrac{2n-1+\omega_1}{2 \omega_1}\rfloor 
\end{equation}
then replace $\omega_1$ with $\omega_2$ to get the next iteration.

If no such $n$ exists, then find an integer $m$ such that
\begin{equation}
k= m + \lfloor \omega_1  m -  \tfrac{\omega_1 }{2} +\tfrac12 \rfloor
\end{equation}
then replace $\omega_1$ with $\omega_2$ to get the next iteration.

It turns out that these two are mutually exclusive: you can always find an $m$ if you can't find an $n$, and vice versa. You can't find $n,m$ which simultaneously works.

Simulating a trajectory for a very large values of $k$, it appears that there is a behaviour similar to a (geometric) random walk. In the literature, it seems to me that something similar happens in the collatz problem, and there are stochastic models as a random walk.

[[image: For a very large initial value of <span class=]$k$, the trajectory appears to resemble a random walk." />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpASK.png)

My question is the following: I am interested in if there is exponential behaviour of the $k$ values, and how `common' this is.

I was wondering if it is possible to approximate this dynamical system by a stochastic model? How could I check if it is valid to think of this process as a random walk? In particular, how could I check that this system has a Markovian property?
I was furthermore interested in if any of the work done by Tao in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.03562.pdf would be valid here or transferable because he appears to explore almost the same question.
I am not too familiar with this area of mathematics so I would tremendously appreciate any ideas on literature to explore.

Comment: This does not bear a "striking resemblance" to Collatz... any more than hundreds of thousands of similar iteration-based problems do.

Comment: "How could I check if it is valid to think of this process as a random walk?" Im no math genious, but you should have open mind when nobody knows how to solve it yet. You should study the problem at more depth you will find more clues.